# How to remove one image from banner?

Tags: jquery, html, css, banner

Let say I have a banner image group.

```
<div class="bannerWrap">
<div class = "banner style="left: 0px;">
<img src = "something.jpg"  id="a">
<img src="something2.jpg" id="b">

</div>
</div>
```

When I move the banner image, only the banner style will be to change
if I want to remove an image file in certain banner location

any good idea?

Comment: you want to remove certain image files, but in what way? and the banner what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the opacity with CSS like this:

```
#a {
    opacity : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code on your `JS` to remove the image with an `id` name of `a`.

```
$('#a').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move image `#a` without effecting image `#b` then set image `#a` to `position:relative`

This allows you to modify the position of image `#a` relative to its original position without affecting the position of image `#b`

Here's what [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) say about `position:relative`:

> ... The element is positioned according to the normal flow of
>   the document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values
>   of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the
>   position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element
>   in the page layout is the same as if position were static.
>
> This value
>   creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto.
>   The effect of relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column,
>   table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

basic example:

```css
.bannerWrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #111;
  display: inline-block;
}

#a {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerWrap">
  <div class="banner">
    <img id="a" src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="Image #a">
    <img id="b" src="https://unsplash.it/300/301" alt="Image #b">
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want to remove image `#a` completely without affecting the layout you can use `visibility:hidden`

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) on `visibility:hidden`:

> ... The element box is invisible (not drawn), but still affects
>   layout as normal. Descendants of the element will be visible if they
>   have visibility set to visible. The element cannot receive focus (such
>   as when navigating through tab indexes).

basic example:

```css
.bannerWrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #111;
  display: inline-block;
}

#a {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerWrap">
  <div class="banner">
    <img id="a" src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="Image #a">
    <img id="b" src="https://unsplash.it/300/301" alt="Image #b">
  </div>
</div>
```